# In a Python list comprehension do you only need an expression and a for loop?

Tags: python

From the Python Crash Course book I was given this block of code as an example:

```
squares = [value**2 for value in range(1, 11)]
print(squares)
```

It says "define the expression for the values you want to store in the new list". I wanted to then play around with this concept and did:

```
import random as r

my_list = [r.random() for value in range(20)]
```

I quickly realized I was not using a variable from the for loop in the expression. I'm assuming then whatever the expression evaluates to will be the value of the list item. Would it be correct to say then you only need ANY expression (variable from for loop not necessary) and a for loop at minimum to use list comprehension?

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions - *"A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses."* As you've demonstrated, the expression does *not* need to use the loop value (same as a regular for loop, where the loop variable is not required to appear in the body) - the convention in these cases is to name the loop variable `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension will work regardless of whether the expression uses the loop variable or not.  So your example will work fine to make a list of 20 separate random numbers.

There is a convention that if a variable that is being assigned is a dummy variable, it is given the name `_`.

```
my_list = [r.random() for _ in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, you can use any expression, given that it is syntactically correct, the expression :

```
[1 for i in range(0,10)]
```

works fine and return a list :

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the iterating variable in our expression or not. It's our wish in list comprehension.
Example:

```
li=[i*2 for i in range(1,10)]
      print(li)
```

or we may neglect the iterating variable

```
li=[23 for i in range(1,10)]
     print(li)
```